# Python ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence

Tags: python

I'm new to Python, and still have much to learn. What am I doing incorrectly and do you have any suggestions?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = list(map(int, input().strip().split()))
    result = filter(lambda x: x != max(arr), arr)
    print(max(result))
```

Comment: what error did you get?

Comment: Welcome to SO - it's generally better to write a descriptive title and include the error message in your question, specifically the entire error message, not just the bit you shared. However, it seems the issue happens on the last line, where you are calling `max()` . Note that this likely happens if the input is just an empty line (user hits enter)

Comment: @Epsi95 - you'll want to look at the title. OP should have included it in the question though.

Comment: you don't need all this. just do `max(input().split())`. In complex scenarios maybe you need to convert the input to an int, use `max([(int(x.strip()) for x in input().split()])`

Comment: alternatively `max(map(lambda x: int(x), input().split()))` or `max(map(int, input().split())`

Comment: @tushortz Yours don't give the second-largest value, do they?

Comment: As an aside, `result = filter(lambda x: x != max(arr), arr)` is a bad algorithm, because you calculate `max(arr)` *for every element in `arr`*. This makes it O(N^2) on the length of `arr`, but if you calculate the `max` once and re-use it then it will be O(N)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

That means your `result` variable is an empty sequence. In this case it would mean that all values in `arr` are the same.

So if you want to not let it raise an error, try setting the default value to `None`, like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = list(map(int, input().strip().split()))
    result = filter(lambda x: x != max(arr), arr)
    print(max(result, default=None))
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the objective of the program is to find the second largest in the sequence. If there is only one element entered, the filter removes the element and result is empty. Thats why you are getting the error

I have made some changes to handle it. Please see if this works

```
arr = list(map(int, input().strip().split()))
result = filter(lambda x: x != max(arr), arr)

if(len(arr)==1):
    print(arr[0])
else:
    print(max(result))
```